# As a non-citizen former resident of Sweden, how do I inform authorities of my new address?

Tags: taxes, sweden

I am a former resident of Sweden, but not a citizen there.  When I moved abroad, I informed the Swedish tax authorities of my new address.  How do I inform the tax authorities of moving from one foreign address to another one?  Neither of two possible forms apply:

- [SKV 7665 Anmälan - Flyttning till utlandet](http://www.skatteverket.se/privat/blanketterbroschyrer/blanketter/info/7665.4.39f16f103821c58f680007072.html).  This form is for the *initial* move abroad, to be filled while still registered as a resident in Sweden.
- [SKV 7842 Anmälan - Ny adress/röstlängd för utvandrad](http://www.skatteverket.se/privat/folkbokforing/flytta/flyttautomlands/nyadressiutlandet.4.18e1b10334ebe8bc80005783.html).  Although this form is for registering a new address while living abroad, it is only for Swedish citizens, as it relates to being registered in the database of Swedish citizens eligible to participate in Swedish elections.

I used SKV 7842, but it seems not to have worked as I did not receive any confirmation.  How do I correctly inform Swedish tax authorities of a new address while living abroad?

Comment: (I have asked the same question to Skatteverket directly.  If I get a useful answer, I will post it here.)

Comment: Probably a very stupid question, but if you are neither a Swedish citizen, not resident in Sweden, would the Swedish tax authorities even care about you?

Comment: @MrLister I had an income in Sweden Jan-Feb 2014, so I suppose that I should file 2014 taxes some time early 2015.  Secondly, the Swedish tax authority doubles as a central registry for addresses from which services such as pension funds but also banks obtain peoples' addresses directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not an exact match but the most reasonable form seems to be:

- [SKV 7842 Anmälan - Ny adress/röstlängd för utvandrad](http://www.skatteverket.se/privat/blanketterbroschyrer/blanketter/info/7842.4.19b9f599116a9e8ef36800024543.html)

This form seems to be intended primarily for Swedish citizens but it is directly applicable to changing foreign addresses.